# Save data from a template into a file in django and send an email

Tags: python, django, email

I have a template in django that shows some information in a table that has the format of a bill with different fields for the unity price, the description, the total price, etc... and i want to, for example, show a button that saves that table into a file and then send an email with that file attached. I wrote Django in the title because thats what im using. Is that the correct way to do it? to save that "table" into a file and then send an email? or maybe someone has another idea to acomplish the same?

**EDIT:** This the table that i have in the template, it makes sum multiplications and addings and completes some boxes with those results.:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div id="">

                <p id="address">
                    {{fact.nombre_cliente}}
                </p>
                <p id= "numero">
                    {{fact.numero_De_Factura}}
                </p>
                <div id="logo">

                  <img id="image" src="{% static 'img/Home/Logo-Exisoft.png' %}" alt="logo" />

                </div>

            </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div id="customer">
            <div id="datos">
                <p id = "direccion">
                    {{cliente.Direccion}}
                </p>
                <br>
                <p id = "direccion">
                    {{fact.RI}}
                </p>
        </div>
        <table id="meta">
            <tr>
                <td class="meta-head">Fecha</td>
                <td><textarea id="date">{{fact.fecha_factura}}</textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="meta-head">CUIT</td>
                <td><div class="due">{{cliente.CUIT}}</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

    <table id="items">
        <tr>
            <th class="tipo">Tipo de Factura</th>
            <th class="descripcion">Descripcion</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item-row">
            <td><div><textarea>{{fact.tipo_Factura}}</textarea></div></td>
            <td class="description"><textarea>{{fact.descripcion}}</textarea></td>
            <td><span class="price">$ {{fact.importe_sin_iva}}</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="totales">
        <tr>
            <td class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
            <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$ {{fact.importe_sin_iva}}</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="total-line">Iva</td>
            <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$ {{iva}}</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  class="total-line">Precio Pagado</td>
            <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$ {{total}}</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
            <td class="total-value balance"><div class="due">$875.00</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

            <div id="terms"></div>        
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
</div>
```

This is what i need to send in an email. I didn't try anything yet because i don´t know what the best approach is. Should i save this table in a file and then print send that file? Is there a way to capture the hole thing and past it in an email and sent it without saving it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is simple, but a bit broad. Most importantly you didn't show what you have tried. You probably want to start with a form view https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/ . Post some of your code and you will probably get better answers.

Comment: hello. i just added the data of the table i want to send. i would apprecite any idea. Thanks

Comment: where are you getting the values for `facturas`?

Comment: I´m really sorry. I mixed up the tables. this is the actual table that i have to send on an email. The values for facturas come from my views.py and they are render in the table. So what do you think is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason to store the the file to be attached as an actual file on the server. Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/

It seems `EmailMessage.attachments` define the files to be attached in terms of (filename, content, mimetype) triples. Use `EmailMessage.attach()` to attach your template rendered as a string (along with a proper file name and mime type), see [`render_to_string()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut). Then use `EmailMessage.send()` to send the email.

You should do this in your view. If using model based views, say `FormView`, you should do it in your `form_valid()` method.  See also http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/